# How can I tell Brunch not to concatenate javascript files?

Tags: brunch

Does anyone know how to configure Brunch not to concatenate javascript files in the local build?

I want the javascript files copied straight over so that I do not have one large javascript file when debugging.

Here's my current `brunch-config.coffee` file:

```
exports.config =
  conventions: ignored: /.+\.spec\.js/
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        'js/app.js': /^app/
        'js/vendor.js': /^(vendor|bower_components)/
    stylesheets:
      joinTo: 
        'css/common.css': /^app/
    templates:
      joinTo:
        'js/templates.js': /^app/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Paul's comment, it is not possible yet to not combine js files when building locally.  Thanks Paul

Answer (score 2):

1. Place your javascript files into `app/assets`
2. Remove `javascripts` and `templates` from your brunch config.

That should just copy them over as-is.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I want them concatenated and uglified only when I create the production distribution, but not local.  Brunch does not uglify locally, I cannot see who I can tell Brunch to not do the concatenation.

Comment: Not possible currently.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why my files _weren't_ concatenating and it turns out I placed them in `assets`, thanks to you I learned that I shouldn't do that ;)